# Update order status based on condition

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I've created a custom field `Customer Level` for users, and I've also created a custom order status `autoprocess`. Now I want to auto-process orders based on customer level:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'auto_process_orders');

function auto_process_orders($order_id) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( $current_user->customer_level >= 5  ) {
        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
        $order->update_status( 'autoprocessed' );
    }
}
```

.. but it just doesn't work. Order stays "on-hold" (since I'm using bank transfer as payment method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it. `woocommerce_thankyou` is the hook to be used.